# Using a different font causes line-height spacing issues in IE6 and IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have a form with a couple of columns and two or three inputs in each. When I just use the default font there is no problem and everything lines up properly but when I use a different font it adds a little vertical space underneath the labels.

the font I'm trying to use is TheMixRegularCaps - http://www.fontslog.com/themix-regularcaps-otf-32939.htm

How can I fix this?

thanks

Comment: Can you post your code? That would be helpful.

Comment: unfortunately it's on my localhost so i can't show you a link

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox You can always just port forward the port you are running it on and send us your I.P.  Here is an example of mine:  http://69.134.44.19:8000

Comment: Are you sure that IE6 is still used by your visitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely the font itself.  Some fonts have more vertical spacing than others.  You should use CSS to attempt to overlap the different labels vertically to make it look like there isn't a large gap.

Take a look at this jsFiddle I just made demonstrating your objective:  http://jsfiddle.net/KWfnq/

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox Just added a jsFiddle to help give you an idea of what to do.