# Line height in textarea (IE7)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a textarea (fixed size), which is getting populated by some text which is then resized to fit (font changed).
The code below runs fine in Chrome, Firefox, etc, but not IE (versions 7/8/9, which it also has to).

In non-IE, the text gets resized and fits in the textares nicely, but in IE there is huge gaps between each line of the textarea.
I have tried setting line-height but it doesn't seem to work. I have read that it is todo with the [height of the font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681282/using-a-different-font-causes-line-height-spacing-issues-in-ie6-and-ie7), which would mean wrapping each line in a span and setting a negative top margin.
Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Code sample;

html

```
<span id="inner-text">
        <textarea readonly="readonly" 
            cols="10" 
            rows="5" 
            class="messagetext" 
            style="width:400px; border:none;height:100px;overflow-y:hidden; resize:none;color: #D31245;"
            >1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15</textarea>
</span><span id="temp" style="visibility:hidden"></span>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    var while_counter = 1;
    var txt = $('textarea.messagetext');
    var font_size = txt.css('font-size').replace(/\D/g,'');
    var scHeight = txt.get(0).scrollHeight;
    var txtHeight = txt.height();
    while ( scHeight > (txtHeight+10) ) {
        font_size = (font_size - 1);
        txtHeight = (txtHeight + 15);
        while_counter = while_counter + 1;
    }

    var lines = txt.val().split('\n');
    var total_lines = lines.length;
    var span_width = $('#inner-text').width() - 5;
    var temp_span = $('#temp');
    // now calculate line wraps
    $.each(lines, function(){
        // temp write to hidden span
        temp_span.html(String(this));
        // check width
        if (temp_span.width() > 400) {
            total_lines = total_lines + 1;
        }
    });
    txt.css('font-size', font_size+'px');
    txt.height( (total_lines * font_size) + (total_lines * 1.14) + 10);
});
```

Comment: No offence but why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Alex, in short because I have to. It is a preview for some text that must fit is a set size area. This text will be output into a document that gets printed.

Comment: The code does not work on Firefox: less than half of the lines fit. Please provide a complete example. There are probably at least some CSS missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy below code in one html file and check in IE

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
alert('hi');
var while_counter = 1;
var txt = $('textarea.messagetext');
var font_size = txt.css('font-size').replace(/\D/g,'');
var scHeight = txt.get(0).scrollHeight;
var txtHeight = $(txt).height();
while ( scHeight > (txtHeight+10) ) {
    font_size = (font_size - 1);
    txtHeight = (txtHeight + 15);
    while_counter = while_counter + 1;
}

var lines = txt.val().split('\n');
var total_lines = lines.length;
var span_width = $('#inner-text').width() - 5;
var temp_span = $('#temp');
// now calculate line wraps
$.each(lines, function(){
    // temp write to hidden span
    temp_span.html(String(this));
    // check width
    if (temp_span.width() > 400) {
        total_lines = total_lines + 1;
    }
});
$(txt).css('font-size', font_size+'px');
$(txt).innerHeight( (total_lines * font_size) + (total_lines * 1.14) + 10);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="inner-text">
    <textarea readonly="readonly" 
        cols="10" 
        rows="5" 
        class="messagetext" 
        style="width:400px; border:none;height:100px;overflow:hidden;resize:none;color: #D31245;"
        >1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15</textarea>
</span><span id="temp" style="visibility:hidden"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: didn't work for me, each line still has extra spacing forcing the content not to fit in the textarea.

Comment: you allowed ActiveX controls in IE (by right clicking bar that showed when you run this file)

Comment: sorry, it seems to work as long as there is a minimum of 12 lines, if the amount of lines is below 12 not all fit after the resize. ANy ideas.

Comment: deepi, thanks very much. I added back in the height declaration, it now works fine in IE7/8. IE9 however, not so much. Any thoughts?